# Mutate multiply columns based on conditional and column name

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with the following structure (See example). The dots after *OperatedIn2007* column signify multiple columns with same name, changing only the year (e.g *OperatedIn2008, OperatedIn2009*, etc.).

I wish to do the following procedure:

- If the *group* is 1, then add one in all columns whose names start with *OperatedIn*.

The expected result should be similar to the one presented in the desired output.

A nonscalable solution would be to use:

```r
df <- df %<%
   mutate(OperatedIn2006 = ifelse(group == 1, 1, 0)) %<%
   [...]
```

I imagine there is some slick solution using *dplyr* or *data.table*, but I could not think of it myself.

**Example**

```
 ID  group OperatedIn2006 OperatedIn2007 ...
 1     1              0              0
 2     2              0              0
 3     3              0              0
 4     4              0              0
 5     1              0              0
 6     2              0              0
```

**Desired output**

```
 ID  group OperatedIn2006 OperatedIn2007 ...
 1     1              1              1
 2     2              0              0
 3     3              0              0
 4     4              0              0
 5     1              1              1
 6     2              0              0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `across` with an `ifelse` statement:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(-c(ID, group), ~ifelse(group==1, 1, .)))
```

```
  ID group OperatedIn2006 OperatedIn2007
1  1     1              1              1
2  2     2              0              0
3  3     3              0              0
4  4     4              0              0
5  5     1              1              1
6  6     2              0              0
```

Comment: So simple yet so effective. How can anyone not love R?

Comment: In a more general dataframe (with other columns besided the ones presented), this method does not work, yes? Do you have an idea how to take on this approach more generally?

Comment: This should work on each dataframe with the same structure independent of the other columns!